# Laravel use randomly created factory for relation

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, factory

I'm trying to seed random belongsTo relationships for a `Post`, but they are all just being created with the same `User` and `Community`.

Code:

```php
        $users = \App\Models\User::factory(100)
            ->create();

        $communities = \App\Models\Community::factory(10)
            ->create();

        \App\Models\Post::factory()
            ->for($users->random()->first())
            ->for($communities->random()->first())
            ->create();
```

After seeding, when I look at the database, the `user_id` and `community_id` is `1` for all of the posts.

How do I make it random for each seeded post based on the users and communities created beforehand?

Tried using `random()` but does not seem to take effect.

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Comment: @Alex v10, already figured it out and posted the answer tho. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out by using `recycle` method in the seeder and specifying a an id for each relationship in the factory.

`PostFactory`:

```php
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'community_id' => Community::factory(),
            'title' => fake()->sentence(),
            'created_at' => fake()->dateTimeThisMonth(),
        ];
    }
```

New seeder code:

```php
        $users = \App\Models\User::factory(100)
            ->create();

        $communities = \App\Models\Community::factory(10)
            ->create();

        $posts = \App\Models\Post::factory(100)
            ->recycle([$users, $communities])
            ->create();
```

Works great now :D

Comment: It probably works because you are creating a new model in your factory, not because you are using the recycle method. Since the reclycle method does exactly the problem you are trying to avoid. I would recommend reading about the [sequences](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#sequences).

Comment: You can use 'user_id' => \App\Models\User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure within a [Sequence](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#sequences) to generate random `user_id` and `community_id` for each `post`. For example:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Sequence;

$users = \App\Models\User::factory(100)->create();
$communities = \App\Models\Community::factory(10)->create();

\App\Models\Post::factory()
    ->count(50)
    ->state(new Sequence(
        fn (Sequence $sequence) => [
            'user_id' => $users->random()->id,
            'community_id' => $communities->random()->id,
        ]
    ))
    ->create();
```

In case your code is exactly the same as the one you have provided, it is better to place the `User` and `Community` creation directly in the post factory.

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Community;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'community_id' => Community::factory(),
            'title' => fake()->sentence(),
            'created_at' => fake()->dateTimeThisMonth(),
        ];
    }
}
```